# Error while using Fuel SDK in Java

Tags: fuel-sdk

I have a simple line of code that I can't get to work.  Will appreciate if someone can let me know what am I doing wrong

```
ETClient etClient = new ETClient(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config\\config.properties");
```

My property file looks like this

```
clientId=<myclientID>
clientSecret=<myPassword>
```

Error that I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setUserData(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.addLocation(StaxUtils.java:953)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.startElement(StaxUtils.java:811)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:880)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:767)
>       at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:219)
>       at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:179)
>       at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:91)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:205)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:148)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:65)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)
>       at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.PartnerAPI.(PartnerAPI.java:49)
>       at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.(ETSoapConnection.java:88)
>       at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapConnection.(ETSoapConnection.java:154)
>       at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.(ETClient.java:156)
>       at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.(ETClient.java:108)
>       at mypackage.ETHelper.(ETHelper.java:21)

Answer (score 0):

The error is explained in the [AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) documentation

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.

So the method `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setUserData` is abstract in the version of Xerces you are using but the Fuel SDK code was compiled against a version of Xerces where the method isn't abstract.

So the fix is to get a more up to date version of Xerces in your classpath.